# How to select a row by a mouse click on Control List in VC++, MFC development

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to use a **control list** with a **report view** to store a file list on a dialog based application like this:
[image]
I have two columns on the control list.

The control list I am using is **Single Selection - True**
My question is how to select the row by a mouse click.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish among columns or you just want the click response to be available on the whole line? For the second case you can define its extended style to be  Full row Select by using: `SetExtendedStyle(GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);`

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  That link you posted provides a class to interact with the CListCtrl.  I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: You have declared `CMyListCtrol m_ListCtrl` and you want to link with ListView control in dialog resource? Override `DoDataExchange`, add `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_ListCtrl)` - [see example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/744110/4603670). Usually you don't need to monitor mouse click. There are methods available to monitor selection change, activate, drag & drop, etc.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, thanks, I will try to see how to add message to the existing control list, but I still want to know how to use a class that is built as MFC Class DLL.

Comment: Never mind. It seems you can already use `CListCtrl` methods, so you must have added subclass somewhere, you probably don't need `DDX_Control`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the click response to be available on the whole line, you can define its extended style to be Full row Select by using:

```
SetExtendedStyle(GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```